# What data to expect in license-maven-plugin third party license FreeMarker template?

Tags: maven, licensing, license-maven-plugin

I'm using the [Mojo License Maven plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/license-maven-plugin/) to generate a list of [third party licenses](http://www.mojohaus.org/license-maven-plugin/add-third-party-mojo.html). According to the documentation I could use a custom FreeMarker template to format the file using the [`fileTemplate` parameter](http://www.mojohaus.org/license-maven-plugin/add-third-party-mojo.html#fileTemplate), but there is no documentation on the data that will be passed to the FreeMarker template. There is a link on the [examples page](http://www.mojohaus.org/license-maven-plugin/examples/example-thirdparty.html) to existsing templates, but that link is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some searching I found the [template on GitHub](https://github.com/mojohaus/license-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/org/codehaus/mojo/license/third-party-file.ftl):

```
...

<#-- To render the third-party file.
 Available context :
 - dependencyMap a collection of Map.Entry with
   key are dependencies (as a MavenProject) (from the maven project)
   values are licenses of each dependency (array of string)
 - licenseMap a collection of Map.Entry with
   key are licenses of each dependency (array of string)
   values are all dependencies using this license
-->
<#function licenseFormat licenses>
    <#assign result = ""/>
    <#list licenses as license>
        <#assign result = result + " (" +license + ")"/>
    </#list>
    <#return result>
</#function>
<#function artifactFormat p>
    <#if p.name?index_of('Unnamed') &gt; -1>
        <#return p.artifactId + " (" + p.groupId + ":" + p.artifactId + ":" + p.version + " - " + (p.url!"no url defined") + ")">
    <#else>
        <#return p.name + " (" + p.groupId + ":" + p.artifactId + ":" + p.version + " - " + (p.url!"no url defined") + ")">
    </#if>
</#function>

<#if dependencyMap?size == 0>
The project has no dependencies.
<#else>
Lists of ${dependencyMap?size} third-party dependencies.
    <#list dependencyMap as e>
        <#assign project = e.getKey()/>
        <#assign licenses = e.getValue()/>
    ${licenseFormat(licenses)} ${artifactFormat(project)}
    </#list>
</#if>
```

It uses this [`LicenseMap`](https://github.com/mojohaus/license-maven-plugin/blob/d57603acf837cd8a665a1cef50a92b4a25019aa0/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/license/model/LicenseMap.java)